# Datepicker inside of scrollable modal

Tags: angular, datepicker, modal-dialog, popup

I wanted to create a scrollable popup with many records and with datepicker. The datepickers stays inside the model beacause of overflow: auto; but it has to be scrollable. Eventually i end up with this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEJUp.png)

```
<div class="inside-form-bottom-buttons-layout"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12" style=""><div class="top-margin-20"><div class="content"><div class="control-input-wrapper"><div class="form-label-input col-sm-4"><label style="text-align:left;">Template - date</label></div><div class="col-sm-8 no-padding-col"><div a2e-datetimepicker="" class="input-group date datepicker ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty" style="height: 100%" ng-reflect-options="[object Object]" ng-reflect-model="25.07.2023"><input class="form-control" tabindex="0" type="text"><div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

i tried making it overflow visible and it worked but only for a few records beacuse later it wasnt scrollable